# How can I end a potion's effect prematurely?

Tags: the-witcher-2

I could have sworn that one of the tutorial journal entries mentioned that meditation could be used to remove potions prematurely (before their duration would normally expire), however I don't see such an option either on the meditate menu, or on the drink potion menu itself.

Is it possible to end a potion's effect prematurely? *Cat* loses its usefullness quite quickly once you leave the dark areas, and I'd rather both avoid the continued visual bleaching effect, *and* the reduced damage to monsters that comes with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you open the meditation menu, you can choose to rest for a specific duration. If you do that, any potion effect will have timed out after your rest.

Comment: Is there no way to selectively remove potions though?

Comment: @Raven there is no way that I know of.

Comment: For what it's worth, the game tells you to meditate to end potions' effects early.